# how to Populate datas into select element by Ajax call using js at first

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a `html` page which contains two select options, it is get the values from a Servlet through ajax call in `onclick()` function. But I at first time data's are not populating into the select options. By next click only the values are populating. I know at first time it just adding the options to the select element. How to populate the data at first click itself. This is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="fName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Age</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="age"></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <td>
                <select name="country" id="country" onclick="loadCountry()">
                    <option selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <td>
                <select name="state">
                    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var status = true;
    function loadCountry()
            {
                var xhttp;
                var cArray;
                var cArrayJs;
                if(status)
                {
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    var selectCountry = document.getElementById("country");
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                        {

                                cArray = this.responseText;
                                cArrayJs = JSON.parse(cArray);
                                for(x in cArrayJs)
                                    {
                                        selectCountry.add(new Option(cArrayJs[x]));
                                    }
                                    status = false;
                                }

                        }
                }

                xhttp.open("GET","servlet1",false);
                xhttp.send();
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you need to fill select list onclick it's not recommended as select list will call ajax request on each click instead on page load you can fill dropdown

Comment: I am new to ajax for learning purpose only I done like that. Also I added flag, at first time it is true, on next time it will set as false, so it will not make ajax call. If it is not proper guide me to write a proper code and where I should use the ajax in proper way

Comment: I think you are on wrong track every time click on select list it will call `loadCountry()` function and every time `status` variable set to true so it doesn't make any sense to do like that if you want to confirm check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ftqshpn/1/) and click on select list and check cosole for more information

Comment: That is a good example, but how can I avoid the ajax call at second time. Give me a example to work for this scenario. And some advice that where should I use ajax and in proper way

Answer (score 0):

As per my point of view that's a best practices to load `selectlist` on page load but if you want to do the same thing on click of dropdown you can do that as follow snippet in which there is only one ajax call will made second time it will not make an ajax call.

I want you to take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bSPEY/139/) too

```js
var loaded = false;
$(".Staus").text(loaded);
$("#country").on("click", function() {
  $(".Staus").text(loaded);
    if (loaded)
        return;
    var selectCountry = document.getElementById("country");
    selectCountry.add(new Option("Hello1"));
    selectCountry.add(new Option("Hello2"));
    selectCountry.add(new Option("Hello3"));
    loaded = true;
  $(".Staus").text(loaded);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" id="country">
</select>
DropDown Loaded : <Label class="Staus"></Label>
```